# REE with Passenger on debian server showing OOPS cannot connect to the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

When I try loading up the webpage: After sometime , it shows opps the google crome cannot connect to the server

### More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

apache error.log:

```
 /var/www/neighborTree-live/shared/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:56:
[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770,
Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.01

[Thu Nov 24 01:10:26 2011] [error] [client 182.72.122.26] Premature
end of script headers: , referer: http://www.neighbortree.com/
[ pid=26090 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:700 time=2011-11-24 01:10:26.66 ]:
The backend application (process 23816) did not send a valid HTTP
response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has
crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this
application.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Passenger process crashed before it could send a response to the browser.
Based on the log, it looks like a problem with the mysql2 gem.  I recommend uninstalling the gem and reinstalling, making sure to use the appropriate version for Ruby 1.8.7.